# Magento ignoring layout rules

Tags: php, magento

Magento 1.9.x

I have these rules in local.xml:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

In the admin panel all categories are set to `Page Layout: No Layout Updates`

And yet all my category pages are on 3 column layouts.

What am I missing?

Comment: if the category design set from admin panel then change from there


 `1. Go to Catalog -> Manage Categories
 2. Select any category
 3. Click the 'Custom Design' tab
 4. Select your desired page layout from 'Page Layout' selectbox
 5. Save Category and you are done!`

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a layout XML solution.

Comment: layout will work if they are not set from admin panel.

Comment: Just to re-iterate, in the admin panel all categories are set to `Page Layout: No Layout Updates` - and yet the layout doesnt work. Any ideas?